# Buying Reserved Instance in Amazon

Tags: amazon-ec2

So I've been running an amazon Linux/Unix micro instance for quite a while, using the free tier. I've been developing an application on it and everything has been working perfectly, however, as I was progressing I noticed the server seemed to be dying every so often. I done some research and found out the reason for that happening was because the Micro instance only had 2 EC2 compute units for short periodic bursts (only had cpu power for about 5 seconds, if any proccess took longer than that its CPU resources were hugely reduced). I figured that the server was dying whenever I was testing my application on it, and because sometimes it would take more than 5 seconds to process something, it would just die.

So because of this I want to upgrade to a small instance, it's not as fast, but it has consistent cpu power, so this will no longer be a problem. I would really like to switch to a Red Hat Linux rather than the system I got with the free tier, but I'm wondering will I be able to move everything from my existing micro instance to the small instance running red hat? As well as that I'm unsure whether to go for the VPC or just the average instance. What would be the advantages and disadvantages of each?

Any help is greatly appreciated as I'm a student and don't really have that much money to be spending, so I kind of have to make the right decision on my first go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If you just stop your existing instance, and then right click on it in the AWS Management console you can switch it to a small instance, and then start it up.
1b) If you want to build a new instance from CentOS or RHEL, you can do this and then migrate all of your data/apps over to the new server.

2) There are many advantages to moving to VPC. You control the internal IP's, you can create security groups for both inbound and outbound machines. The problem, is for just 1 server, you add complexity that's probably not necessary.

3) You didn't ask this question, but it is the title of your post, so I will answer it. If your server runs 24x7,you will get significant savings by purchasing a reserved instance.

Comment: Thanks! I'll probably build a new instance with RHEL, and because I'm not planning in adding more servers any time soon the VPC is propably unnecessary.

Comment: if you use CentOS it will be cheaper as well.. CentOS is the free version of RHEL